# How to replace text in a "li"

Tags: html, javascript, jquery

I have about 100 pages all with an `<ul>` - the problem is, I need to wrap each list item in a `<span>`. I've added the code below

```
<ul style="list-style-type: disc; margin-left: 40px; line-height: 140%;" _mce_style="list-style-type: disc; margin-left: 40px; line-height: 140%;">
    <li> ICD-10 transition </li>
    <li> Pricing transparency </li>
    <li>Patient and payor mix fluctuation<br>&nbsp;</li>
</ul>  

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").each(function (index) {
        $("li:nth-last-child(" + index + ")").append(" <span>" + $("li:nth-last-child(" + index + ")").text() + "</span>");
    });
});
```

This is the result I get:

> ICD-10 transition ICD-10 transition ICD-10 transition
>
> Pricing transparency Pricing transparency Pricing transparency
>
> Patient and payor mix fluctuation
>
> Patient and payor mix fluctuation  Patient and payor mix fluctuation

The code is being replaced twice when I only want the code to run once and replace the code one time - not twice. I'd like to know how to fix this but more so why this is even happening in the first place. The method isn't being called twice - so why is it happening.

---

Thank you guys so much for helping me figure out!!! I got it working with this...

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

        $("li").each(function (index) {
            $(this).html("<span>" + $(this).html() + "</span>");

        });
    });
```

Thank you so very much!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 6):

You can do it like following.

```
$("li").each(function () {
    $(this).html('<span>'+$(this).html()+'</span>');
});
```

Comment: He does not need `index` any more. Checkout [**This Demo**](http://jsbin.com/wogavenoyu/edit?output)

Comment: I don't use index. @sємsєм

Comment: I know but why you passed it as a function's parameter?! This is what I, exactly, mean.

Comment: Oh! got it. Thanks for pointing out. That was my lack of sincerity. @sємsєм

Comment: With some explanation your answer would be perfect. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 5):

This is happening because when you append the `span` you keep the text in the `li`, so it is showed twice. You can change the [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) in order to *clear* the content in the `li` and replace with the new `span`:

```
$("li:nth-last-child(" + index + ")").html(" <span>" + $("li:nth-last-child(" + index + ")").text() + "</span>");
```

[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zL7qezLb/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li:nth-last-child(" + index + ")").append(" <span>" + $("li:nth-last-child(" + index + ")").text() + "</span>");
```

Append adds onto the list element content.

You can do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").each(function (index, el) {
        $(el).html(" <span>" + $(el).text() + "</span>");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("li").wrap("<span></span>");
});
```